# KendoUI Angular2 grid column filter type filter="date" No component factory found for undefined

Tags: angular

When I set kendo angular 2 column filter="date" it's give me an error

```
<kendo-grid-column field="RevisionDate" title="Rev Date" filter="date" format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
```

Error is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

What should be the reson, Please help me to fixed this.

[image: screenshot]